# IndexingError: Too many indexers for Python filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I was following the [tutorial: Python Pandas Tutorial (Part 4): Filtering - Using Conditionals to Filter Rows and Columns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw2rlcxScZY). At around time 11.30, the author made a filter. I tried to do the same with sample data:

```
    id          Date        ITEM_ID TYP YearMonth   VALUE
0   13710750    2019-07-01  SLM607  O   2019-07     10
1   13710760    2019-07-01  SLM607  O   2019-07     10
2   13710770    2019-07-03  SLM607  O   2019-07     2
3   13710780    2019-09-03  SLM607  O   2019-09     5
4   13667449    2019-08-02  887643  O   2019-08     7
5   13667450    2019-08-02  792184  O   2019-08     1
6   13728171    2019-09-17  SLM607  I   2019-09     1
7   13667452    2019-08-02  794580  O   2019-08     3
```

reproducible example

```
data = {
    "id": [
        13710750,
        13710760,
        13710770,
        13710780,
        13667449,
        13667450,
        13728171,
        13667452,
    ],
    "Date": [
        "2019-07-01",
        "2019-07-01",
        "2019-07-03",
        "2019-09-03",
        "2019-08-02",
        "2019-08-02",
        "2019-09-17",
        "2019-08-02",
    ],
    "ITEM_ID": [
        "SLM607",
        "SLM607",
        "SLM607",
        "SLM607",
        "887643",
        "792184",
        "SLM607",
        "794580",
    ],
    "TYPE": ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "I", "O"],
    "YearMonth": [
        "2019-07",
        "2019-07",
        "2019-07",
        "2019-09",
        "2019-08",
        "2019-08",
        "2019-09",
        "2019-08",
    ],
    "VALUE": [10, 10, 2, 5, 7, 1, 1, 3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

with code:

```
mask =(df['VALUE']>0)
dfx.loc[mask, ['ITEM_ID', 'TYPE']]
```

and caught error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-841-88806e1eb3d9> in <module>
      1 mask =(df['VALUE']>0)
----> 2 dfx.loc[mask, ['ITEM_ID', 'TYPE']]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1759                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1760                     pass
-> 1761             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1762         else:
   1763             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1274 
   1275         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
-> 1276         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   1277 
   1278         # ugly hack for GH #836

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    698         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    699             if i >= self.ndim:
--> 700                 raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    701             try:
    702                 self._validate_key(k, i)

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You are using `dfx` instead `df` is that typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you filter another DataFrame, `dfx` instead `df` and then change column name `TYPE` to `TYP`:

```
mask =(df['VALUE']>0)
df = df.loc[mask, ['ITEM_ID', 'TYP']]
print (df)
  ITEM_ID TYP
0  SLM607   O
1  SLM607   O
2  SLM607   O
3  SLM607   O
4  887643   O
5  792184   O
6  SLM607   I
7  794580   O
```